# jQuery slidetoggle for outside navigation elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation where there are 4 clickable links. Those links will then drop-down a menu and display content, note that the content is not directly under the links in the code. Here is an image of how it currently looks like:

[image]

I need jQuery to make it slidetoggle down when clicking any of the links (Ladies, Men, Junior, Stores). I got that working so far, however when clicking the other three (while the first is active) shouldn't make it go back up and instead display the content of that specific nav link and hide the previous clicked link' content.

e.g. clicking Men while previously having clicked ladies will set display none on the ladies content and will display the men' content instead. So the navigation should only slide back up when the same navigation unit is clicked twice (first to activate, second to close).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Malachute/yxC8L/

If possible, it should also .addClass to the current active navigation link. What would the jQuery code for this be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question, I altered the fiddle, please tell me if that is wished behaviour:)
If not I will try to help again:)
[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AyNSS/)

Comment: That looks what I'm looking for. Thanks! Will be home in a few hours to test it out. Will report back.

Comment: Got it working with your code! Last questions: how do you use .addclass to add "current" to the active menu li element?

Comment: Another fork event with class toggle http://jsfiddle.net/DxLsD/ ..It is might possible to make this in better way, but I am tired now and this is working:)
And please check my answer as acceptet:)Thanks